# I want to delete from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, replace, innerhtml

I have innerHTML like this:

```
<img class="ytimg" src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mKt-MDwtVB4/hqdefault.jpg" >
  <div class = "videotext" >
    <h5> Bootstrap tutorial #1</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
```

I want to delete every single word and tag from it and I want to keep only one thing.

This: `mKt-MDwtVB4`

My code now:

```
alert(this.innerHTML.replace(//g,''))
```

Comment: `My code now` - seriously? you think that will somehow know what you want?

Comment: No. I don't think that. But I tried doing this for a hour. I didn't want to post my crap here. lol

Comment: Please make sure your question title and description actually match. We have n clue about what tech you're using, but as AFAIU you want to extract an information from a string. If so, my thinking is that you need regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see how you get the containing element whose innerHTML you're working with, so there's an assumption first up with the div id="something"

```js
var blah = document.getElementById('something');
var img = blah.querySelector('#ytimg');
var split = img.src.split('/');
split.pop();
blah.innerHTML = split.pop();
```

```html
<div id="something">
  <img class = 'ytimg' id='ytimg' src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mKt-MDwtVB4/hqdefault.jpg" >
  <div class = "videotext" >
    <h5> Bootstrap tutorial #1</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But that should do exactly what you want without RegExp - which may summon Tony the Pony

What the code does is

1. Gets the element whose innerHTML you want to change
2. gets the img with id="ytimg" within that element (a bit redundant as there's only ever one element with that ID in a page
3. splits the src attribute (URL) of the image on the / character
4. pops and discards the last part of the URL
5. pops the second last part, the part you want and replaces the innerHTML with that part of the URL

Comment: Ok. I have a tags. I want this code to do the following: If I click any of the a-s, It'll give me that „youtube id”, but only the clicked one's. So I can't give an ID to a div. Any suggestion?

Comment: you've got the innerHTML from somewhere, I can't see how, surely you can amend the code to suit your needs - or post more information in the question on HOW you're getting the innerHTML - because I can't make sense of the comment

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. This should do it:

```js
var all_images_src = document.getElementsByClassName('ytimg');
for(var i = 0; i < all_images_src.length; i++){
    var img_src = all_images_src[i].getAttribute('src')
        img_src = img_src.replace('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/', '');
        img_src = img_src.substring(0, img_src.lastIndexOf("/"));
    console.log(img_src);
}
```

```html
<img class='ytimg' src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mKt-MDwtVB4/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class='ytimg' src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mKt-xxxxxxx1/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class='ytimg' src = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mKt-xxxxxxx2/hqdefault.jpg">
 
<div class="videotext">
    <h5> Bootstrap tutorial #1</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, now I realized. I will modify my answer.

Comment: I can't add an ID, because I have more then 20 links like this, I need a function to work for all of them.